# Drag and drop image to other div by making clone image in angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working in angular.js. I have some pretty simple requirement of Drag and drop image from one div to other div. I am trying to clone drag-able image and and drop in my defined div so that it shouldn't remove from the list. can any one help me about the same. below is the [link](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable/blob/master/example-clone.html) which i have tried to use. guide me for image drag-gable

Comment: If you want to clone and drag to other div, you need to use some javascript plugin like Raphael JS..

Comment: Have you check above given link of github? I just want to clone the image instead of div .

Comment: Ya. I also mean same. Use RaphaelJS.. It will solve your all problem..